# Is the absolute value of zero positive or negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

If I had $|x|$, then we know, for pretty much any $x$, that the following is true:$$|x|\ge0$$$$|0|=0?$$Which, by the nature of how we usually apply the absolute value, the solution is positive and real.

But that would make $|0|$ positive?

And since it equals itself, then I have come to the solution that $0$ is positive.

Which has become a contradiction?  Because $-0=0$, therefore what?

Is the absolute value of zero defined easily? And is it positive?

According to the comments, the absolute value of $x$ is not negative, so the absolute value of $0$ is not negative either?

Comment: $|x|\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Indeed $|0|=0$.

Comment: $| \cdot |$ is non-negative, but not positive

Comment: @Alex Wait, what?

Comment: $|x|\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $|0|=0$. There is no contradiction: we have $|0|=0\ge 0$.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: it's neither.

Comment: I'm not sure why it hasn't showed up yet, but the usual definition is $$\lvert x \rvert = \begin{cases}x, &x \ge 0\\-x, &x < 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Actually I've seen definitions stating "0 is the only number which is both positive and negative", which makes full sense to me. $\pm 1$ would then be STRICTLY positive/negative ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$|x|\geqslant 0$$

Absolute value is not strictly positive but it's non-negative. Zero doesn't have any sign. For example we define $\operatorname{sgn}(0) = 0$ whereas all other numbers satisfy $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\pm 1$.

Comment: @SimpleArt [Sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

Comment: So could you say that the absolute value is non-negative?

Comment: @SimpleArt yes, it is. You cannot say $|x|$ is always positive because for $x=0$ it's neither positive nor negative.

Comment: So what does that mean for $0$?  It's like saying 1 is on and 0 is off, but the solution is 1/2.

Comment: (sgn(x)) It's like saying a positive number is 1 and a negative number is -1, but 0 is 0, so what does that mean for 0?

Comment: @SimpleArt it means that $0$ is special. This is the only solution to $x=-x$.

Answer (score 2):

You mistake is the statement 'But that would make $|0|$ positive?'. No, it would not. Absolute value makes the expression non-negative, but not everywhere positive.

Answer (score 1):

No, the absolute value of zero is zero. For real numbers, the law of trichotomy states that every real number is either positive, negative, or zero. $|0|=0$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is necessarily the correct way to look at this, but could you not consider the absolute value function $|x|$ to be the distance function in $\mathbb R$, applied to $x$ and $0$, i.e. the distance of $x$ from $0$ (written $d(x,0)=d(0,x)$)? Then the distance from $0$ to $0$ is obviously $0$.

Comment: That sort of brings me back to saying that the distance from $0$ to $0$ is positive, which it has appeared to obviously not be (completely).

Answer (score 1):

The word "positive" is ambiguous: it can mean "$\ge 0$" or "$>0$". You can distinguish these two cases by calling them "non-negative" and "strictly positive".

Comment: That is helpful (+1)

Comment: And to add to the ambiguity, the usual meaning of "positive" alone is not the same in every country. In France, you usually say positive for $\geq0$ and strictly positive for $>0$. In anglo-saxon countries, I believe positive is $>0$ and $\geq0$ is non-negative. The best is to always be explicit. For $\geq$, it's also frequent to see "positive or null", at least in France.